# How to implement proxy mode in Postgresql server

Tags: postgresql, redirect, tcp, debian, postgresql-9.1

Postgresql 9.1 server is running in Debian 6 Linux under VPS and accessed by IPV4 address from clients.

I want to move it to other VPS server with never Debian and PostgresSQL 11.

How to implement this so that clients can use same IP address ?
Is it possible to force Postgres to redirect requests to other IP ?

Debian has redir demon  ( https://manpages.debian.org/testing/redir/redir.1.en.html )
Is it best way to use it to redirect requests to 5432 port to other server ?

Answer (score 0):

Yiu have several options:

- If you control the DNS server, map the name to the new IP address.
- Install pgBouncer on the old machine - in session pooling mode, it will work as a proxy.
- Start an SSH tunnel on the old machine that redirects the requests to the new machine.